# Matrix integration over the orthogonal group

Tags: integration

Is there an easy argument why the following statement is true?

Let $O(d)$ be the orthogonal group and $\mu$ a Haar measure. Let $U\in O(d)$. Then $\int\limits_{O(d)}U\:d\mu(U)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V=\int_{O(d)}Ud\mu(U)$.  You know $V$ is $O(d)$ invariant, so $V=-V$.
Or: for each $a\in\mathbb R^d$ of unit length, you know $Ua$ is uniformly distributed over the sphere, and hence $Va=\int_{O(d)}U\,a\,d\mu(U)=0$.